# How to avoid this error? ICEBERG COMMIT ERROR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-iceberg

**encountering error while executing below query,can someone help with this?**

```
MERGE INTO {processed_db}.{processed_table} target
USING (
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY {key}
ORDER BY COALESCE(transact_id,'0') DESC) AS row_version_number,
*
FROM (
SELECT op, {",".join(columns)}
FROM "{raw_db}"."cdc_{raw_db}_{processed_table}"
{filter_condition}
) raw_data
) versioned_raw_data
WHERE row_version_number = 1) source
ON  {merge_filter}
WHEN MATCHED AND source.op = 'D'
THEN DELETE
WHEN MATCHED
THEN UPDATE SET {", ".join([f"{col} = source.{col}" for col in columns])}
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND source.op <> 'D'
THEN INSERT ({",".join(columns)})
VALUES ({",".join(["source." + col for col in columns])})
```

can someone pls let me know the reason?
TIA.